# Blazor javascript method cannot be called

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, javascript-interop

I am trying to call a javascript function from my Blazor component using JSinterop but I always get this error :

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input".

Plus the javascript function is being called automatically when the page is fully laoded which is not the demanded behavior, because i want to trigger the  function when a button is clicked.

```
@page "/jsInterop"
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<h3>JSinterop</h3>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
 onclick="@setLocalStorage()">
    Trigger JavaScript Prompt
</button>

@code{

public object setLocalStorage()
{
    return jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("interop.setItem", "username", 
"Aymen");
}
}


window.interop = {

    setItem: function (name, value) {

        window.localStorage[name] = value;
        return value;
    },

};
```

Comment: Might be removing parenthesis to function call `setLocalStorage` - `onclick="@setLocalStorage"` will work.

Comment: Hi @randomSoul , It doesnt Work , it rasises and error , and it says : cannot convert methdo group to none delegate type "object".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error where you have the onclick event

```
onclick="@setLocalStorage()"
```

Should be

```
@onclick=“@setLocalStorage”
```

All Blazor events now need to be prefixed with an @.

You also need to change the signature of your click handler and you should await the call.

```
public async Task setLocalStorage()
{
    await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("interop.setItem", "username", 
"Aymen");
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the "async" keyword in order to use "await "  @Chris Sainty